# Causing infinite loop for SharePoint 2010 Approval Workflow using SharePoint Designer

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to setup an approval workflow for new and edited items in Document Library.

I created an approval workflow that is set to start when a new item is created and when an item is edited.  The workflow updates the approval status on completion.

Now when I create a new item or edit an existing item the workflow kicks off as expected.  However when I approve the workflow the workflow completes and then starts a new workflow.  It would seem that updating the approval status is causing the workflow to activate again.

Is there any workaround to stop this looping?

Comment: You set which users approve the item?

Comment: It is still in the development process, so I am approving it as I am site owner.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for SharePoint workflows because of the synchronous events which will be triggering in the back end. so as a workaround you need to have an conditional check on some hidden fields such as "flags" so it doesn't interrupt your actual requirement though it triggers another workflow event.

say : if you set the flag to 1 on completion. keep the initial condition to start the workflow only when the flag is 0 along with other conditions. this would resolve your problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? And if we are updating the flag value, won't it consider as a change? Because on completion of the workflow, I am updating the drop-down column value (that has the workflow status) which is instantiating the workflow again.